# Gaps when recording sensor data in Android application

Tags: android, android-studio, record, sensors

I am writing an Android application to record sensor data (acceleration gyroscope magnetometer calibrated and uncalibrated) and write them to a txt file, however, if I try to record for a long time, I get gaps in the data.

**Questions**:

- I want to know what are some possible reasons for that?
- Is it a memory issue?

**How the signal looks like**:

[image: how the signal looks like]

The code has 2 classes:
-IMUmeasurement class: this class has the attributes (x,y,z,time ,xclai,ycali,zcali,timecali) two main methods setxyz (that takes uncalibrated sensor events and fills the variables x y z and time) setxyzcali (that takes sensor events from calibrated sensor and fills the variables xcali ycali zcali and timecali)
-IMUdata: this class has functions: createfile (that creates the file), getIMUcallback ( to Register listener) logIMUdata (to write sensor events to file)

The idea is in the IMUdata class I created a vector of IMUmeasurement in the begining , whenever I get to sensor listener I add an IMUmeasurement object to the vector. Once the size of the vector is 5, I write the vector to the file. I have put the code with the main methods below

```
//Main activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ImuData imuData; // A class I created to register sensor data
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] permissions = {


        imuData = new ImuData();
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnStart.setEnabled(true);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                imuData.onDestroy();
            }
        });

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnStop.setEnabled(true);
                btnStart.setEnabled(false);
                imuData.CreateFile(MainActivity.this);
                imuData.GetIMUcallback();
            }
        });



//class IMU measurement
public class ImuMeasurement {
    /**
     * IMU measurement of IMU sensor
     */
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;
    public float caliX;
    public float caliY;
    public float caliZ;

    /**
     * boolean indicators
     */
    public boolean isSet = false;
    public boolean isCaliSet = false;

    /**
     * time when the IMU measurement events are listened from the IMU sensor
     */
    public double time;
    public double timeCali;

    /**
     * parse the time and uncalibrated data into the object
     * @param Event
     */
    public void setXYZ(SensorEvent Event){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmssSSS");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        Log.i("TIME", "" + date);
        time = TimeTransfer(strDate);

        X = Event.values[0];
        Y = Event.values[1];
        Z = Event.values[2];
        isSet = true;

        Log.i("SENSOR", "" + X + "," + Y + "," + Z);
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * parse the time and calibrated data into the object
     * @param Event
     */
    public void setXYZ_cali(SensorEvent Event){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmssSSS");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        Log.i("TIME", "" + date);
        timeCali = TimeTransfer(strDate);

        caliX = Event.values[0];
        caliY = Event.values[1];
        caliZ = Event.values[2];
        isCaliSet = true;

        Log.i("SENSORcali", "" + caliX + "," + caliY + "," + caliZ);
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * reset the object as empty
     */
    public void resetIMUdata(){
        isSet = false;
        isCaliSet = false;
    }

}

public class ImuData {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;             //Sensormanager
    private Vector<ImuMeasurement> accObservations;   //vector of the acc object
    private ImuMeasurement accMeasurement;            //object including 6 values of accelerometer&gyro output
    private StringBuilder fileContentsImu;            //string builder
    private File parentDir;                           //main directory of the file created by this application
    private File surveyDir;                           //sub directory difference by date
    private File surveyTimeDir;                       //sub directory difference by time
    private File fileACC;                             //acc file name
    /**
     * override the Listener to get the SensorEvent of uncalibrated accelerometer measurements
     */
    private SensorEventListener listenerAcc = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent Event) {

            // if the object is null, create one
            if(accMeasurement == null)
            {
                accMeasurement = new ImuMeasurement();
            }

            accMeasurement.setXYZ(Event);
            Log.i("SENSOR", "Acc activated");

        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * override the Listener to get the SensorEvent of calibrated accelerometer measurements
     */
    private SensorEventListener listenerAcc_cali = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent Event) {

            // if the object is null, create one
            if (accMeasurement == null) {
                accMeasurement = new ImuMeasurement();
            }

            accMeasurement.setXYZ_cali(Event);

            if (accMeasurement.isSet == true && accMeasurement.isCaliSet == true) {
                //add the object into the vector
                accObservations.add(accMeasurement);

                //set the isAccSet and isGyroSet to false
                accMeasurement.resetIMUdata();

                //set the object to null to receive new measurements
                accMeasurement = null;
            }

            //when the vector stored 5 IMUmeasurement
            if (accObservations.size() == 5) {
                //log into file
                logImuData(accObservations,"acc");
                //remove the elements of vector and set it as empty
                accObservations.removeAllElements();
                //}

                Log.i("SENSOR", "AccCali activated");

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }

    };

 private void logImuData(Vector<ImuMeasurement> imuObservations, String type){

        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;

        if(imuObservations == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Log.i("FILE", " " + fileContentsImu + " ");

        //we append new contents to file
        if (type == "acc") {
            fileImu = fileACC;
            for (ImuMeasurement meas:imuObservations) {
                if (meas.time - meas.timeCali < 1e-3)
                {
                    fileContentsImu.append(meas.time)
                            .append(",")
                            .append(meas.X)
                            .append(",")
                            .append(meas.Y)
                            .append(",")
                            .append(meas.Z)
                            .append(",")
                            .append(meas.caliX)
                            .append(",")
                            .append(meas.caliY)
                            .append(",")
                            .append(meas.caliZ)
                            .append("\n");
                }
                try {
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileImu, true);
                    outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                    outputStreamWriter.append(fileContentsImu);

                    outputStreamWriter.close();
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //clearing contents to next loop
                fileContentsImu = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you managing state? Could it be that the screen turned off? or the app was not in the foreground? That would explain the gaps in data.

Comment: I tried it with the screen on for a whole 2 minutes it still gave me the same result.  What do you mean by managing state. How can I keep the app in the foreground?and is it possible to record the data when the screen is off? Thank you @Chrystian